# Rails 4 - Nested Routes and Form Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I'm trying to create a new "participation" in my Rails4 application and it seems like there is something wrong with my parameters. Actually this is not causing any problems in application (or I didn't notice it) but still I would like to fix it. You can see 2 "examination_id" parameters one of them is null and the other one is equal to 1.

**REQUEST PARAMETERS:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XZ71eV0zxrnTBilzvEtLlHLwoAb+qKdDfxOHjrAHUPg=",
 "participation"=>
   {
    "language_preference"=>"Türkçe",
    "exam_center_preference"=>"1",
    "disability"=>"1",
    "user_id"=>"1",
    "examination_id"=>""
   },
 "commit"=>"Sınava Başvur",
 "examination_id"=>"1"
}
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :examinations do
  resources :participations do
    member do
      get :update_profile_information
    end
  end
end
```

**participation.rb:**

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :examination
  before_save :verification_key_generator
end
```

**participations_controller.rb:**

```
class ParticipationsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_participation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :get_examination

  def get_examination
    @examination = Examination.find(params[:examination_id])
  end

  def index
    @participations = @examination.participations
  end

  def show
    @participation = @examination.participations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @participation = Participation.new
  end

  def create
    @participation = @examination.participations.new(participation_params)
    @participation.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @participation.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@examination, @participation], notice: 'Başvuru işlemi başarıyla tamamlandı!' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: [@examination, @participation] }
      else
        render 'new'
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @participation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @participation.update(participation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@examination, @participation], notice: 'Başvurunuz Başarıyla Güncellendi!' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: participation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_participation
      @participation = Participation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def participation_params
      params.require(:participation).permit(:user_id, :examination_id, :payment_status, :language_preference, :exam_center_preference, :disability)
    end
end
```

**app/views/participations/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@examination, @participation], html:{class: "well"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id } %>
  <%= f.input :examination_id, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :language_preference, collection: ["Türkçe", "İngilizce", "Rusça"], label: 'Sınav Dili Tercihi' %>
  <%= f.input :exam_center_preference, collection:ExamCenter.all, label: 'Sınav Merkezi Seçiniz', label_method: :city %>
  <%= f.input :disability, inline_label: 'Yardımcı İstiyorum', label: false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sınava Başvur" %>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/participations/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@examination, @participation]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :language_preference, collection: ["Türkçe", "İngilizce", "Rusça"], label: 'Sınav Dili Tercihi' %>
  <%= f.input :exam_center_preference, collection:ExamCenter.all, label: 'Sınav Merkezi Seçiniz', label_method: :city %>
  <%= f.input :disability, inline_label: 'Yardımcı İstiyorum', label: false %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id } %>
  <%= f.input :examination_id, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sınava Başvur" %>
<% end %>
```

sa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using

```
<%= simple_form_for([@examination, @participation], html:{class: "well"}) do |f| %>
```

to generate the form, it will set the action to be `/examinations/[examination_id]/participations` so the routes/action will know the `examination_id` from the url itself.

So, you don't need to pass `examination_id` separately as hidden field that you're setting as

```
<%= f.input :examination_id, as: :hidden %>
```

Once you remove this hidden field the request parameters will look like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XZ71eV0zxrnTBilzvEtLlHLwoAb+qKdDfxOHjrAHUPg=",
 "participation"=>
 {
   "language_preference"=>"Türkçe",
   "exam_center_preference"=>"1",
   "disability"=>"1",
   "user_id"=>"1"
 },
 "commit"=>"Sınava Başvur",
 "examination_id"=>"1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working well.